# VBA Function vs Sub

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a repeated line in a report using the code below.  I want it to be a function I can call from a cell but when I change "sub" to "function", my variable Waldo changes from a Range type to Nothing.

```
 Set Waldo = wb.Sheets(Sheet_Name).Cells.Find(What:=Find_This, After:=Sheets(Sheet_Name).Range("A1"), LookAt _
                :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                False, SearchFormat:=False)

'skip the first found instance and go to the specified line

    If Line_Num > 0 Then
        While Line_Num > 0
            Set Waldo = wb.Sheets(Sheet_Name).Cells.FindNext(After:=Waldo)
            str = Waldo.Value
            MsgBox str
            Line_Num = Line_Num - 1
        Wend
    End If

stringArray() = Split(str, " ", -1)
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix this?  Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You can't use `FindNext` in a UDF called from a cell. Use Find again with all the same parameters (other than the `After` one).

Comment: what is the initial value of Line_Num and what are the arguments to the function (assuming this is the whole function body)

Comment: Many ways to do it. For a user define function see [THIS - Section 5](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Comment: Challenging how the question is framed: I assume you are looking for an address of the repeated line so that you can manage the duplications? A combination of COUNTIF, INDEX/MATCH and ADDRESS formula in native excel could provide a robust solution. COUNTIF tells you if there are any (shortcutting the INDEX/MATCH if it not required) and the ADDRESS provides the cell address where the duplicate is eventually found.

Comment: Rory solved it thanks.  Thanks also to Siddharth for the reference.